# watchOS ExtensionDelegate does not get run

Tags: watchkit, watchos-4

I started a new iOS App with WatchKit App from the Xcode template.  I have done this a few times before and have not had issues.  For some reason the ExtensionDelegate does not seem to run.  I have a breakpoint set in applicationDidFinishLaunching() but it does not get hit.

Instead a breakpoint in InterfaceController awakeWithContext gets hit first.  Is there a place that this gets configured in order to fix why the ExtensionDelegate launch code does not get run?

Answer (score 3):

Verify that Info.plist for the WatchKit Extension still has the key `WKExtensionDelegateClassName` set with the correct value for your `ExtensionDelegate`.

By default it is set to `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ExtensionDelegate`, maybe you deleted or modified it by error.

Comment: I had an old project and after I converted the ExtensionDelegate to swift I found that the Info.plist entry was `ExtensionDelegate` not `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ExtensionDelegate` so this really saved me, thanks!